# Do I dare clicking Delete Volume instead of Delete Partition?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, vmware, logical-drive

I have a VMWare machine with one VM. That VM has a virtual disk which in windows is configured  with two partitions and then a lot of slack space.

What I want to do is delete the partition of 639 GB. However, since it's a dynamic disk, the right menu item says "Delete Volume" instead of "Delete Partition" (when I right click the 639GB space).

My question is weather I dare to use "Delete Volume". I have read doing stuff like this on a dynamic volume can cause other partitions/volumes to go corrupt.

Comment: Why do you think that you have a dynamic disk? The screen shot you have provided clearly shows that it is a basic disk.

Comment: I read somewhere that if I have the "Delete volume" option instead of the "Delete partition" option, then I have a dynamic disk. Anyway, the question still remains. Do I dare or not?

Comment: Microsoft TechNet says this: "If the menu item reads Delete Volume instead of Delete Partition, the volume is a dynamic volume. For instructions on how to delete a dynamic volume, see Related Topics."

Comment: And what read the 'Related Topics'? ;)